# Issue with very simple python3 program

Tags: python, python-3.x

Complete noob with python 3.  I have some code and can't figure out for the life of me why I keep getting the output I do.  For some reason the elif statements aren't getting recognized.  Here is the output first and the code down below:

```
3
Your fortune for today is:  
Please press enter to end
```

```
#Program for fortune cookies

var1 = "It's going to be a good day"
var2 = "You'll have a long life"
var3 = "Your life will be short"
var4 = "Things will be good"
var5 = "Life will be fun"
import random

randNum = random.randint(1, 5)
statement = ""
print(randNum)
if randNum == 1:
    statement = var1
elif randNum == 2:
    statement = var2
elif randNum == 3:
    statement == var3
elif randNum == 4:
    statement == var4
elif randNum == 5:
    statement == var5

print("Your fortune for today is: ", statement)
input("Please press enter to end")
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not assigning `varx` to `statement` (in some cases, 3, 4 and 5th cases), but comparing. Just change all:

```
statement == varx
```

To:

```
statement = var3
```

Except from that, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the lines:

```
elif randNum == 3:
    statement == var3
elif randNum == 4:
    statement == var4
elif randNum == 5:
    statement == var5
```

'==' is for checking equality, '=' is for assigning variables.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is for example

```js
statement == var5
```

assignment statement.

Good luck!